# question mark operator in expressions

Tags: c, operators

*K&R Second Edition* (page 71)-- I must have missed the explanation:

```
sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
```

The context of this is a function that converts a string to a double. This part in particular comes after the function skips white space. **I infer it is** checking for positive or negative value, and saving it as either -1 or +1 for sign conversion at the end of the function... `return sign * val /power;`

**I would like to do better than infer...** I'm particularly unsure of what the `?` and `: 1` are doing here (or anywhere, for that matter).

It kind of seems like an abstract `if` statement. Where `?` checks for truth and `:` is `else`... is that so? Is it limited to `if/else`?

I am a beginner and I haven't come across this expression syntax before, so I am wondering if there is a particular reason it seems to often be replaced by a formal `if/else`--besides, perhaps, readability?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> It kind of seems like an abstract if statement.

That's correct. This is called a "ternary conditional operator".

The normal `if` works on *statements*, while the conditional operator works on *expressions*.

---

> I am wondering if there is a particular reason it seems to often be replaced by a formal if/else--besides, perhaps, readability?

There are cases where branching on statements is not enough, and you need to work on the expression level.

For instance, consider initialization:

```
const int foo = bar ? 5 : 3;
```

This could not be written using a normal `if`/`else`.

---

Anyway, people who are saying it's equivalent to the `if`/`else` are being imprecise. While the generated assembly is usually the same, they are not equivalent and it should not be seen as a shorthand version of `if`. Simply put, use `if` whenever possible, and only use the conditional operator  when you need to branch on expressions.

Comment: Chosen as answer because you addressed the why, as well as the what.

Answer (score 21):

> It kind of seems like an abstract if statement, where `?` checks for truth and `:` is else... is that so?

Yeah, almost. It's called the "conditional operator" (sometimes not entirely accurately referred to as "the ternary operator", since it's the only ternary operator in C). It's not a **statement** though, it's an **expression,** it has a value. It evaluates to its second argument if the first argument evaluates to true, and to its third argument if it's false. Therefore

```
sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (s[i] == '-') {
    sign = -1;
} else {
    sign = 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for helpfulness. This answer really explains how the "conditional operator" is interpreted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is the ternary operator. `(s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;` returns `-1` if `s[i] == '-'` and `1` otherwise. This value is then assigned to `sign`. In other words, a longer way to write this would be:

```
int sign;

if(s[i] == '-')
{
  sign = -1;
}
else
{
  sign = 1;
}
```

Comment: "The ternary operator" is not entirely correct, its proper name is "the conditional operator".

Answer (score 2):

`?:` is the *conditional operator* in C.

In your example it would produce the same result as this `if` statement:

```
if (s[i] == '-')
{
    sign = -1;
}
else
{
    sign = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
```

is shorthand for:

```
if (s[i] == '-')
{
    sign = -1;
}
else
{
    sign = 1;
}
```